# Pyspark schema treeString to schema object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the output of the printSchema() (a treeString) in a txt file. Is there a pyspark API to parse the string and create the schema object?

Example Input:

```
root
 |-- num: long (nullable = true)
 |-- letter: string (nullable = true)
```

Example Output:
spark schema object

`StructType(List(StructField(num,LongType,true),StructField(letter,StringType,true)))`

Comment: Does your text file only contains header ? How are you getting your actual data ?

Answer (score 1):

As for as I know, there is no such thing to convert a Big output print (came from `printSchema() that basically returns None.`  to an actual pyspark object.
In order to do it, you will have to create the schema on your own.

Write a parser that does it for you, but its pretty useless, just work with `DF.schema` that return's what's you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the same, but should work. Instead of using treeString, use json string.

```
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType


serialized = df.schema.json()
deserialized = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(serialized))
```